Memory leak while defining a firedac connection
I have created a pooled connection using firedac, placing  FDServerManager FDWaitCursir and FDphysMySQLDriverlink on a datamodule and on DataModuleCreate I have written a method that reeds a file named conn.ini
procedure TDataModule2.DataModuleCreate(Sender: TObject);
var
  oParams : TStringList;
  cdir, fname : string;
  fs : TFileStream;
  sr : tStreamReader;
 begin
   cdir := GetCurrentDir;
   fname := 'conn.ini';
   try
     fs := TFileStream.Create(cdir+TPath.DirectorySeparatorChar+fname, fmOpenRead);
     try
       sr := tStreamReader.Create(fs, TEncoding.UTF8);
       try
         oParams := TStringList.Create;
         while not sr.EndOfStream do
           oParams.Add(sr.ReadLine);
         FDManager1.AddConnectionDef('MySQL_pooled', 'MySQL', oParams);
       finally
         sr.Free;
       end;
     finally
       fs.Free
     end;
   except
      on E: EFileStreamError do
         showmessage('file not found '+e.Message);
   end;
end;

the ini file
[MySQL_pooled]
Server=localhost
User_Name=franz
Password=franz
Database=mydb
Pooled=false
POOL_MaximumItems=100

I prepared a form for testing the connection
procedure TForm1.bnConnectClick(Sender: TObject);
begin
   DataModule2.FDConnection1.ConnectionDefName := 'MySQL_pooled';
   DataModule2.FDConnection1.Connected := true;
   ShowMessage('OK')
end;

the connection is OK but whet i close the application I receive a memory leak

but i don't know why. Any suggestion?

You could almost have guessed the answer to this Q. Indeed, you have two instances of the standard Frog := TFrog.Create; try { use Frog } finally Frog.Free; end pattern, one time with fs := TFileStream.Create and one time with sr := TStreamReader.Create. Both "constructions" are properly matched with "destructions". But then you have oParams := TStringList.Create all alone, with no matching try..finally oParams.Free. Even the error message you get suggests that the TStringList is the problem. (In your defence, one could suspect that AddConnectionDef takes ownership of the...)

Also, you should remove your entire try..except thing. You don't even know if the file is not found.

Thank you Andreas why you say "you should remove your entire try..except thing. You don't even know if the file is not found." if i remove the file it does not execute any line and exit. Thank you for support

EFileStreamError may be raised even if the file exists. In that case, you are lying to the end user when you tell him/her that the file was "not found". Better to remove the try..except altogether. You will get a message box in case of exception anyway (but with no lies).

Why are you not using TIniFile or TMemIniFile at all?

really do not know i'll try

It seems like you don't destroy oParams.

Error that you get said TStringList ist not destroyed. Set your TStringList free.
   oParams := TStringList.Create;
   try
       while not sr.EndOfStream do
       oParams.Add(sr.ReadLine);
       FDManager1.AddConnectionDef('MySQL_pooled', 'MySQL', oParams);
   finally
     FreeAndNil(oParams);
   end;


You should protect the string list with a try..finally block.
